# i need to pass a map within the body of http request in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this map : 
**Map messageReplayParams = {
"content": text,
 "files": ["111111","222222"]
};**
and I need to serialize this map to JSON and send it to the body of a POST request.
notice that the map has a list of strings called files.

Comment: And? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to do this var
 messageReplayParamsEncode = json.encode(messageReplayParams);
but the files in the response always null